# Проблемы после установки админки Yii2 yii2-admin

Tags: yii2, composer, админка

У меня на `Yii2` через composer установлены `yii2-user`, `yii2-rbac`. После того как установил админку `yii2-admin`. При попытке выйти в браузер `.../index.php?r=admin`, выводит сообщение: `Call to undefined method User::find()`. Дело в том, что модель User - это не `ActiveRecord`, а `class User extends \yii\base\Object` `implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface`. Но, если переделать её под `ActiveRecord`, то ни на одну страницу нельзя выйти.

Вот рисунок ошибки, помогите решить проблему:

[image: Описание ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему. Просто я создал через gii модель User2 типа ActiveRecord, работающую с таблицей user (БД). А в настройках конфигурации написал, что класс, работающий с пользователями будет User2:

```
'controllerMap' => [
             'assignment' => [
                'class' => 'mdm\admin\controllers\AssignmentController',
                'userClassName' => 'app\models\User2',
                'idField' => 'user_id'
            ]
        ],
```